# Image.Save() throws GDI+ exception for image derived from bitmap

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio, bitmap, gdi+

I have two classes: ChartObject & GrowthChartPane.

ChartObject has a method, GetChart(), that converts a bitmap to a Drawing.Image that is returned.

```
    Public Function GetChart() As Drawing.Image
    Dim chartImage As Drawing.Image
    Dim gr As Graphics
    Dim brush As Brush = Brushes.Blue
    If m_bIsBoy Then
        brush = Brushes.Red
    End If

    Using fs As New FileStream(m_sChartImageFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        chartImage = Bitmap.FromStream(fs)
        gr = Graphics.FromImage(chartImage)
    End Using

    For Each Point As PointObject In m_lstUpperPoints
        If Not Point.IsVisible Then Continue For
        Dim x As Integer = m_objUpperHorizontalAxis.ValueToPoint(Point.HorizontalValue)
        Dim y As Integer = m_objUpperVerticalAxis.ValueToPoint(Point.VerticalValue)
        gr.FillEllipse(brush, New RectangleF(x - 4, y - 4, 8, 8))
    Next
    For Each Point As PointObject In m_lstLowerPoints
        If Not Point.IsVisible Then Continue For
        Dim x As Integer = m_objLowerHorizontalAxis.ValueToPoint(Point.HorizontalValue)
        Dim y As Integer = m_objLowerVerticalAxis.ValueToPoint(Point.VerticalValue)
        gr.FillEllipse(brush, New RectangleF(x - 4, y - 4, 8, 8))
    Next
    DrawHeaderAndTable(gr)

    Return chartImage
End Function
```

GrowthChartPane, when it is loading, makes a call to ChartObject.GetChart() to instantiate a Drawing.Image object. When trying to Save the image that is returned from growth chart, the exception occurs. The method is pretty big, but here is a snippet from the end where the exception is.

```
            Dim fn As String = PediatricGrowthChartsImageHandler.GetPGCImagePath(CurrentPatient.EntityID, m_iChartTypeId)
        If Not IsNothing(customDrowingChart) Then
            Dim chartImage As Drawing.Image = customDrowingChart.GetChart()
            hdnImgChartH.Value = chartImage.Height.ToString 'test
            hdnImgChartW.Value = chartImage.Width.ToString 'test
            chartImage.Save(fn, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            chartImage.Dispose()
            imgChart.ImageUrl = String.Format("PediatricGrowthChartsImageHandler.axd?PatientID={0}&PGCTypeID={1}&rnd={2}", CurrentPatient.EntityID, m_iChartTypeId, New Random().NextDouble().ToString())
        Else
            Chart1.SaveImage(fn, ChartImageFormat.Png)
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(DataToBeFilled) Then DataToBeFilled.dispose()

End Sub
```

I have confirmed that the file does NOT exist, yet exception is still thrown on Image.Save()

I've done some research on this topic & there are so many different solutions out there, but that brought me to a concern about the stream being open. 
I've read that the stream needs to be open to Save an image and that you can directly pass a stream into the Save() method, but I 'm curious about how that interaction goes between the two classes.

Comment: _"that converts a bitmap to a Drawing.Image"_ A `Bitmap` _is_ already an `Image`. Anyway, what's the value of `fn`? Are you sure you have write permission for that path? Moreover, please provide all the [exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: First thing I'ld change (in `GetChart()`) is `Dim chartImage As Bitmap = Nothing (...) chartImage = DirectCast(Image.FromStream(fs).Clone(), Bitmap)`.

Comment: Exception details = 'A generic error occurred in GDI+' ; thrown at chartImage.Save ()... wasn't very helpful for me. Also, value of fn is not a local path. It's string value is something like "\\CTFSLOL1.dev\webdata\charts

Comment: ok, the output shows this ! "Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' in System.Drawing.dll
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed ^^

Comment: It appears that the error is on `Chart1.SaveImage(fn, ChartImageFormat.Png)`.